# centering elements in a grid

Tags: graphics

We have used below code to generate a grid

```
 redCircle = Graphics[{Red, Disk[Scaled[{.01, .01}]]}]; 
  greenCircle = Graphics[{Green, Disk[Scaled[{.01, .01}]]}];

  grids = Grid[{

      {"Numbers", "Se-1", "Se-2", "Se-3"},
      {"result1", redCircle, greenCircle, greenCircle},
      {"result2", greenCircle, redCircle, redCircle}},


   ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.1], Scaled[.06], Scaled[.06], Scaled[.06]}, 1},
   Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]
]
```

Although, we exploit `Alignment` in order to center circles in their cells of the grid but unfortunately we could not do that. How can we center circles in their own cells?

Comment: What do you mean by "...unfortunately we could not do that" ? It did not work for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
redCircle = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{1, 1}, Scaled[{.25, .25}]]}];  
greenCircle = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{1, 1}, Scaled[{.25, .25}]]}];

grids = Grid[{{"Numbers", "Se-1", "Se-2", "Se-3"}, {"result1", 
redCircle, greenCircle, greenCircle}, {"result2", greenCircle, 
redCircle, redCircle}}, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.1], Scaled[.06], Scaled[.06], Scaled[.06]}, 
1}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

This would do just fine[image]